# Is it ever possible that echo in php will work like var_dump also?

Tags: php

I'm not taking about programming in php but php itself.
Is it possible that creators of php will make echo to dump for example arrays like
the var_dump does?

Comment: Why should they if there is already an appropriate function, namely `var_dump`?

Comment: Why when var_dump and print_r both exist to do just this?

Comment: Changing echo to do the same as var_dump() would break a lot of existing PHP code, leaving only print (printf, etc) for displaying variable values rather than variable information

Comment: The reason is to code more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that creators of php will make echo to dump for example arrays like the var_dump does?

I think you mean if `echo` gets passed a variable that can not be displayed as a string, show a dump, instead of the current behaviour of showing its data type (e.g. `Array`)?

That would indeed make sense, but also be dangerous: What if an object contains data that the end user is not supposed to see?

I doubt the  `echo` function (or, to be more exact, the string parsing functions of PHP) will undergo such a radical change, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @stereofrog I'm talking about backwards compatibility. Changing the output from `array` to a full variable dump *would* be a radical change.

Comment: Yes.Dumping if varaible cant be displayed. Backwards compatibility would be issue i didn't thought about.

Answer (score 2):

Such a radical change to existing functionality would be a recipe for a lot of broken code. So I'd say no.

That said, this is PHP we're talking about, so it wouldnt surprise me....

Comment: What? PHP tends to defer to a lot backwards compatibility. Even though it's a disaster, `register_globals` is still available. If you want massive backwards compatibility break, see python.

Answer (score 2):

in php you can create an object that walks like an array and quacks like an array, but still is an object with a customizable __toString method.

```
class ary implements ArrayAccess
{
 function __construct() {
  $this->a = func_get_args();
 }
 function offsetExists($k) {
  return isset($this->a[$k]);
 }
 function offsetGet($k) {
  return $this->a[$k];
 }
 function offsetSet($k, $v) {
  $this->a[$k] = $v;
 }
 function offsetUnset($k) {
  unset($this->a[$k]);
 }
 function __toString() {
  return implode(', ', $this->a);
 }
}

$a = new ary(11, 22, 33);
$a[1] = 66;
echo $a;
```

of course, it would be better is arrays already were normal objects like in other languages, but i don't think this is going to happen in the nearest future.